# Extracting XML Document from XML Node

Tags: xml, xslt

I am receiving a XML Document, which has in one of the nodes another XML Document. Like this for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <doc>&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;UTF-8&quot;?&gt;&lt;root&gt;&lt;content&gt;&lt;/content&gt;&lt;/root&gt;</doc>
</root>
```

So far i have been reading the value of the  tag to a string and then used the loaded it to another XML Document.

The problem is now that i ran into encoding problems with special characters like ä,ö,ü...

Is there a way to use xslt in order to solve this task of extracting the xml document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try to use :

```
<xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping='yes' select="/root/doc" />
```

?

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make it work. One last detail that took me some time was that i suddenly had a duplicate XML Declaration. But i was able to solve it using the omit-xml-declaration="yes" parameter in the xsl:output tag